# Multiply matrix rows by element row of vector

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have a `2x2` matrix and I want to multiple each row by the same row element in `2x1` vector. How can I accomplish this in R?

**Example:**

```
w1 <- matrix(c(0,1, 2, 3), ncol = 2)
v1 <- matrix(c(0, 6), ncol = 1)
```

**Multiplication**

[ (0 * 0), (2 * 0) ] = [0, 0]

[ (1 * 6), (3 * 6) ] = [6, 18]

**Desired output**

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    6   18
```

Comment: You could also use `sweep` like this: `sweep(w1, MARGIN=1, STATS=v1, FUN="*")`, but keeping V1 as a vector and using element-wise multiplication is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you express your vector as a vector, rather than as a matrix, it works:

```
m <- matrix(c(0,1,2,3), nrow = 2)
v <- matrix(c(0, 6), nrow = 2)

> m*as.vector(v)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    6   18
```

Or, call it as a vector from the start:

```
m <- matrix(c(0,1,2,3), nrow = 2)
v <- c(0,6)

> m*v
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    6   18
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `apply`:

```
w1 <- matrix(c(0,1, 2, 3), ncol = 2)
v1 <- matrix(c(0, 6), ncol = 1)

apply(w1, 2, `*`, v1)
```

The second argument tells `apply` to use the function `*` on each column of `w1`. `v1` is an argument to `*`.

Comment: Thanks, it is that easy. I was wondering if there is matrix multiplication operation, but this works too.

Comment: For matrix multiplication as we know it from linear algebra use `%*%`.

Answer (score 1):

One option is:

```
w1 <- matrix(c(0,1, 2, 3), ncol = 2)
v1 <- matrix(c(0, 6), ncol = 1)
w1*v1[,1]
#       [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    0
# [2,]    6   18
```